# How to only include specific div element to a page in php?

Tags: php

Is this possible? I have not seen this kind of codes. I really wanted to implement this but i was not able to search for it or I do not know how this kind of execution is called.

On a php page I have this elements of divs.

```
elements.php

<div id="countries">
<p>Malaysia</p>
<p>India</p>
</div>

<div id="cities">
<h2>sihgn</h2>
<p>sighn city</p>
</div>

<div id="street">
<h2>nowhere</h2>
<p>somewhere</p>
</div>
```

and on the showcountryonly.php which displays the specific div only.

```
<?php include (elements.php)?> ???? echo div #countries
```

on the showcitiiesonly.php which displays the city only.

```
<?php include (elements.php)?> ???? echo div #cities
```

on the showstreetonly.php which displays the street div only.

```
<?php include (elements.php)?> ???? echo div #street
```

The reason I want to implement this is I want to only edit one page for all of my includes.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a variable for each div in `elements.php`:

```
$countries = '<div id="countries">
<p>Malaysia</p>
<p>India</p>
</div>';

$cities = '<div id="cities">
<h2>sihgn</h2>
<p>sighn city</p>
</div>';

$streets = '<div id="street">
<h2>nowhere</h2>
<p>somewhere</p>
</div>';
```

After including the elements file, you can just echo the needed variable:

```
<?php
include (elements.php);
echo $countries; // $cities or $streets
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the most perfect asnwer. thank you for quick response.

Comment: Glad I could help, @james. Cheers!